# simple swap program not working javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, swap

I've made the following swap function:

```
function swap(a,b)
{
    var c=b;
    b=a;
    a=c;
}
```

It is supposed to swap 2 numbers.
I have the follwing code:

```
var x=5;
var y=10;
swap(x,y);
```

The problem is that when I output the vaues of these variables after swap I still get 5 for x and 10 for y.
Any ideas?

Comment: The **values** of `x` and `y` are passed into `swap`, not the variables themselves (or a reference to them).

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameters are passed by value you cannot write a function that replaces the following:

```
var a, b;
var temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

You can also use a one-liner:

```
b = [a, a = b][0];
```

Comment: Or just: `[a, b] = [b, a]` (as of late 2014 (Safari) to mid March 2016 (Chromium))